# Stop Angular http Observable stream closing on error

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive, angular-httpclient

I have a Subject (this.searchSubject) which I call next() on when I want to perform a search:

```
this.searchSubject.next(postBody)
```

This causes the following to fire:

```
this.searchSubject
      .switchMap((view: any) => {
         // upsert here records the search - needed
         return this.searchHistoryService.upsert(view)
          .flatMap(() => this.http.post(this.url, view))
          .map((data) => this.pageTransform(data));
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.successSubject.next(this.pageTransform(res));
      }, err => {
        this.errorSub.next(err);
      });
```

Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I can't seem to keep the stream alive if `this.errorSub.next(err);` is called (the error condition).

Since the httpClient (this.http.post) returns a new observable each I wouldnt have thought handling the error would be an issue, but it seems this removes all observers from this.searchSubject.

Note I have a httpInterceptor which returns a thrown error for every error returned.

This must be an extremely common pattern, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which `rxjs` version are you using?

Comment: upwards of 5.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error handler is in the outer switchMap projection, thus it will close the outer stream in case of an error. You'll have to move it inside to your `switchMap` to keep the outer stream alive.

And since you're using `rxjs@5.5.2` you can use the lettable operators which might make it easier to see where to put your error handlers.

```
this.searchSubject.pipe(
  switchMap((view: any) => {
   return this.searchHistoryService.upsert(view)
    .pipe(
      flatMap(() => this.http.post(this.url, view)),
      map((data) => this.pageTransform(data)),
      catchError(() => {
        this.errorSub.next(err); 
      })
    );
  })
).subscribe(() => {
  this.successSubject.next(this.pageTransform(res));
});
```

An important note if you switch to the lettable operators is that you have to import them from `rxjs/operators` like `import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';`
.

If you stay with the old syntax I think it will be as easy as to add a `.catch` after your `.map()` projection.

Comment: Thanks for this, I figured out that the outer observable was being closed as you said, its just a case now of trying to get my solution like yours, although i hadnt seen catchError, will that mean no error will be raised to searchSubject?

Comment: The `catchError` is just a rename of the old `catch` since the latter is a reserved keyword. Exactly, you'll have to handle the error inside.

Comment: You have to return something to catchError, so I return an Observable.of(err), which calls the success method in the subscription. Any idea how to avoid returning this?